# Text box won't expand

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Adobe Illustrator - All of a sudden my text bounding box appeared without anchors so I can't expand it, instead it wants to link to other boxes. Never happened before - any ideas? It's likely I accidentally pressed a combination of buttons but all the other docs I have opened from the past or anything new I try has the name problem

Answer (score 1):

- Go to 'View → Show Bounding Box'
- or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>